# How long does it take for steam to reject a gift automatically if the receiver don't confirm receipt?

Tags: steam

If I gift a game to my friend, but he does not click confirm, then how long before it will be rejected automatically by the system?

It's near the summer sale now. If my friend gifts me a game, and I do not confirm receipt, but instead wait for the summer sale to see if the price will be lower. Assuming the price is lower, I would ideally reject the gift, have my friend get the refund, and then have them buy the game for me at the lower price. Also, could we be banned for this type of behaviour?

Comment: I don't think Valve would ban you for being a smart shopper!

Answer (score 2):

If you buy a game with extra copies and donate one of the copies, then there's no expiration ([Steam support page](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4502-TPJL-2656#giving)).

Otherwise gifts expire in thirty days ([Steam support page](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=549#expire)).

Gifting to more expensive regions might be impossible if the price difference is too high. Other restrictions are listed on the store page. I can't find any information that a sale would affect gifting refunds.

Comment: Can he get refund if I decline the gift more than 2 week?

Comment: The support page does not mention a reason why your friend wouldn't get a refund. They are refunding the gift to the sender after thirty days if it's not accepted anyway.